# Using Spring Boot together with gRPC and Protobuf

Tags: spring, spring-boot, protocol-buffers, grpc

Anyone having any examples or thoughts using gRPC together with Spring Boot?

Comment: https://spring.io/blog/2015/03/22/using-google-protocol-buffers-with-spring-mvc-based-rest-services is probably a nice read.

Comment: True, already found that one. But I would like to know if anyone has tied this together with protobuf service definitions as well?

Comment: Looking for an example too

Comment: I recommend using [yidongnan/grpc-spring-boot-starter](https://github.com/yidongnan/grpc-spring-boot-starter). It supports both server and client as well as Spring-Security, Metrics and many more features and examples. **Disclosure**: I'm one of the core maintainers of that library. If you have any question regarding that library feel free to open an issue there.

Comment: https://github.com/abhinavsinghvirsen/grpc-app simple example maven springboot

Answer (score 41):

If it's still relevant for you, I've created gRPC spring-boot-starter [here](https://github.com/LogNet/grpc-spring-boot-starter).

*grpc-spring-boot-starter* auto-configures and runs the embedded gRPC server with *@GRpcService-enabled* beans.

The simplest example :

```
@GRpcService(grpcServiceOuterClass = GreeterGrpc.class)
public static class GreeterService implements GreeterGrpc.Greeter {

    @Override 
    public void sayHello(GreeterOuterClass.HelloRequest request, StreamObserver<GreeterOuterClass.HelloReply> responseObserver) {
      // omitted 
    }

}
```

There is also an example of how to integrate the starter with Eureka in project's README file.

Comment: If you want to use the "same" library for both client and server i recommend using [yidongnan/grpc-spring-boot-starter](https://github.com/yidongnan/grpc-spring-boot-starter). It also has Spring-Security support. **Disclosure**: I'm one of the core maintainers of that library.

Comment: Isn't there any support provided by spring boot for gRPC and protobuf as a starter dependency, like the ones for data-jpa, logging, testing etc. ?

Comment: The https://github.com/LogNet/grpc-spring-boot-starter is unofficial one. At this moment spring team does not provide starter for grpc.

Comment: does attribute autowiring occur with instantiating via @GrpcService ?

Comment: The service will be instantiated via spring's bean factory, autowiring works as-is.

Comment: yep, just looked into annotation, and saw there @Service )) nice.

Answer (score 5):

https://github.com/yidongnan/grpc-spring-boot-starter

In server

```
@GrpcService(GreeterGrpc.class)
public class GrpcServerService extends GreeterGrpc.GreeterImplBase {

    @Override
    public void sayHello(HelloRequest req, StreamObserver<HelloReply> responseObserver) {
        HelloReply reply = HelloReply.newBuilder().setMessage("Hello =============> " + req.getName()).build();
        responseObserver.onNext(reply);
        responseObserver.onCompleted();
    }
}
```

In client

```
@GrpcClient("gRPC server name")
private Channel serverChannel;

GreeterGrpc.GreeterBlockingStub stub = GreeterGrpc.newBlockingStub(serverChannel);
HelloReply response = stub.sayHello(HelloRequest.newBuilder().setName(name).build());
```

Answer (score 5):

If you need a gRPC **client** library, i.e. consume stubs, check out my library https://github.com/sfcodes/grpc-client-spring-boot

This library will automatically scan your classpath, find all gRPC stub classes, instantiate them, and register them as beans with the ApplicationContext; allowing you to easily `@Autowire` and inject them just like you would any other Spring bean. For example:

```
@RestController
public class GreeterController {

    @Autowired  // <===== gRPC stub is autowired!
    private GreeterGrpc.GreeterBlockingStub greeterStub;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/sayhello")
    public String sayHello(@RequestParam String name) {
        HelloRequest request = HelloRequest.newBuilder().setName(name).build();
        HelloReply reply = greeterStub.sayHello(request);
        return reply.getMessage();
    }
}
```

For gRPC **server** library, I'd also recommend `LogNet/grpc-spring-boot-starter`.

Answer (score 2):

Starting from https://spring.io/blog/2015/03/22/using-google-protocol-buffers-with-spring-mvc-based-rest-services, then
take a look at 
[SPR-13589 ProtobufHttpMessageConverter support for protobuf 3.0.0-beta4](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-13589) and related [SPR-13203
HttpMessageConverter based on Protostuff library](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-13203)

That is some support for proto3 is coming in Spring 5. As it is under development one is encouraged to vote and raise what is important for their project.

Comment: https://github.com/WThamira/gRpc-spring-boot-example is correct example for that case I think

Answer (score 0):

**Ref - [Spring Boot 3 + gRPC Example](https://www.javainuse.com/boot3/grpc2)**

gRPC, short for Google Remote Procedure Call, is a high-performance open-source framework developed by Google. It facilitates communication between client and server applications, allowing them to call methods on each other as if they were making local function calls.

Consider a banking service where the the client needs to get the account balance. For this a unary gRPC call is made to the server which returns the balances.
[image]

For this we need to add the following dependencies -
**spring-boot-starter-parent**- We have used version - 3.2.0. It provides default configurations, dependencies, and plugins that are commonly used in Spring Boot applications.
**grpc-server-spring-boot-starter**- We have used version - 2.15.0. Which is the latest dependency provided by maven repository. It provides the necessary components to integrate and run a gRPC server within a Spring Boot application.
**grpc-stub**-- We have used version - 1.59.0. This dependency provides classes and utilities for creating and using gRPC stubs, which are used to make remote procedure calls.
**grpc-protobuf**-- We have used version - 1.59.0. This library provides support for the Protocol Buffers serialization format used in gRPC, allowing you to define and exchange structured data between your gRPC client and server.
**annotations-api**- We have used version - 6.0.53. This artifact provides the necessary annotations for Java code generated by the protobuf-maven-plugin.

Also we make use of a maven plugin, called protobuf-maven-plugin. This is used to compile Protocol Buffers (protobuf) files in a Maven project. Protocol Buffers is a language-agnostic data serialization format. This plugin takes the protobuf files (defined in the specified directory) and generates Java code from them. This code enables communication between different components of the application, making it easier to exchange data in a structured and efficient manner.

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.javainuse</groupId>
    <artifactId>boot-unary-grpc-server</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.0</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <protobuf.version>3.17.3</protobuf.version>
        <protobuf-plugin.version>0.6.1</protobuf-plugin.version>
        <grpc.version>1.59.0</grpc.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.devh</groupId>
            <artifactId>grpc-server-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <version>2.15.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.grpc</groupId>
            <artifactId>grpc-stub</artifactId>
            <version>${grpc.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.grpc</groupId>
            <artifactId>grpc-protobuf</artifactId>
            <version>${grpc.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
            <artifactId>annotations-api</artifactId>
            <version>6.0.53</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <extensions>
            <extension>
                <groupId>kr.motd.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>os-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.7.1</version>
            </extension>
        </extensions>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.xolstice.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>protobuf-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.6.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <protocArtifact>
                        com.google.protobuf:protoc:3.24.0:exe:${os.detected.classifier}
                    </protocArtifact>
                    <pluginId>grpc-java</pluginId>
                    <pluginArtifact>
                        io.grpc:protoc-gen-grpc-java:1.59.0:exe:${os.detected.classifier}
                    </pluginArtifact>
                    <protoSourceRoot>
                        ${basedir}/src/main/proto/
                    </protoSourceRoot>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>compile</goal>
                            <goal>compile-custom</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Answer (score -1):

In here I use gRpc and eureka to communication. This project based on Spring-boot

https://github.com/WThamira/grpc-spring-boot

additionally you canuse register as consul also. full example in this repo

https://github.com/WThamira/gRpc-spring-boot-example

this maven dependency help to gRpc

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.grpc</groupId>
            <artifactId>grpc-stub</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.grpc</groupId>
            <artifactId>grpc-protobuf</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.grpc</groupId>
            <artifactId>grpc-netty</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
```

and need plugin show in below

```
       <plugin>
                <groupId>org.xolstice.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>protobuf-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.5.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <!-- The version of protoc must match protobuf-java. If you don't depend 
                        on protobuf-java directly, you will be transitively depending on the protobuf-java 
                        version that grpc depends on. -->
                    <protocArtifact>com.google.protobuf:protoc:3.0.2:exe:${os.detected.classifier}</protocArtifact>
                    <pluginId>grpc-java</pluginId>
                    <pluginArtifact>io.grpc:protoc-gen-grpc-java:1.0.1:exe:${os.detected.classifier}</pluginArtifact>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>compile</goal>
                            <goal>compile-custom</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
```

Answer (score -1):

In this Github Repo[1] you will find an example of using gRPC to insert and view the users into the couchbase db. Please refer the proto file[2] to find the rpc methods.

Normally gRPC clients like bloomRPC is used to access the service. Using envoy proxy it is possible to transcode and access the service using HTTP/1.1. In the readme file the steps of creating a config file and to run the envoy proxy using docker file is shown.

[1] https://github.com/Senthuran100/grpc-User
[2] https://github.com/Senthuran100/grpc-User/blob/master/src/main/proto/user.proto

Answer (score -1):

Created a simple Springboot App with GRPC. This GitHub repo has both Server and Client examples. Repo has separate Maven module(grpc-interface) where we declare the Proto files and generate the Java source code then can be used as lib in both Server and client apps.

https://github.com/vali7394/grpc-springboot-repo

Answer (score -1):

you can use this page.
dependency and build tags was provided.
'https://www.baeldung.com/grpc-introduction'

Answer (score -1):

I've launched a project called [grpc-starter](https://github.com/DanielLiu1123/grpc-starter). The goal of this project is to enable smoother integration between the gRPC ecosystem and Spring Boot, it embraces Spring Boot 3. The main features include:

- Autoconfiguration for gRPC server/client(support `@Autowired`)
- JSON transcoder
- Integration with [proto-gen-validate](https://github.com/bufbuild/protoc-gen-validate)
- Exception handling
- Dynamic refreshing

Here's a simple example:

```java
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableGrpcClients("io.grpc")
public class SimpleApp extends SimpleServiceGrpc.SimpleServiceImplBase {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new SpringApplicationBuilder(SimpleApp.class)
                .properties("grpc.client.authority=127.0.0.1:9090")
                .run(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void unaryRpc(SimpleRequest request, StreamObserver<SimpleResponse> responseObserver) {
        SimpleResponse response = SimpleResponse.newBuilder()
                .setResponseMessage("Hello " + request.getRequestMessage())
                .build();
        responseObserver.onNext(response);
        responseObserver.onCompleted();
    }

    @Bean
    ApplicationRunner runner(SimpleServiceGrpc.SimpleServiceBlockingStub stub) {
        return args -> {
            SimpleResponse response = stub.unaryRpc(SimpleRequest.newBuilder().setRequestMessage("World!").build());
            System.out.println(response.getResponseMessage());
        };
    }

}
```

Worth a try!