# Start an embedded gRPC server while running integration tests with Springboot

Tags: spring-boot, spring-boot-test, grpc-java, testcontainers

I have built a Springboot application which has a gRPC server as one of its dependencies. While running the integration test, I am able to use embedded Kafka, embedd MySQL etc using TestContainers, but how can I create an embedded gRPC server while running my integration test suite?

I have the .proto contract definition file. I would use Wiremock to mock the request and responses to the gRPC server, but I am unable to start the embedded gRPC server yet.

It will be really great if I could find some help here.

Come to think of it, my question can be generalized to starting a generic embedded HTTP server in Springboot integration test, using TestContainers or otherwise.

Comment: Would this be useful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31938242/using-spring-boot-together-with-grpc-and-protobuf ?

Comment: The two repos shared there are worth looking into. However, it seems to me that they are not talking about using a gRPC server in an integration test environment. I myself  figured out how to set up a mocked gRPC server for integration testing, which I will provide as an answer to this question.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem with IT testing Java gRPC service integrations, as using `InProcessServer` is quite cumbersome and quite hard to use when you need to return different responses for different tests. Also when using it you cannot really test your `Stub` beans and their configuration, since you can't pass `InProcessServer` host as a variable.

For this purpose I've created a gRPC Java mocking tool [gRPC Mock](https://github.com/Fadelis/grpcmock). It has two integration modules - one for spring-boot and one for JUnit5. It follows a similar DSL type of structure to HTTP mocking service WireMock for creating the stubs. You can visit the GitHub page for some examples.