# How to bootstrap a gRPC application with Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot, grpc, grpc-java

Trying to create both gRPC and HTTP APIs in my single Library Spring Boot Application to getBookList

Comment: This could help  - https://www.baeldung.com/grpc-introduction

Comment: The answers to this post might be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31938242/using-spring-boot-together-with-grpc-and-protobuf